# Run an app on a multiple devices automatically in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have two Android devices connected to my computer. When I try to run the app from Android Studio, then it always prompt me to choose the device. Is there any way to deploy the app on a multiple devices automatically - by clicking Run or even better with a shortcut?

Comment: Presumably you could script usage of the adb shell `am` command which you can find in the android docs or in numerous questions here, use something like xargs or a for loop to iterate over all the devices, and then configure the IDE to run the script from a custom button or menu.  If you are also expecting a (re-) install, you'll need to `adb install -r somefile.apk` in your script first.

Answer (score 308, accepted):

This is almost too easy, actually. When you see the list of devices come up after launching the app, just shift or control click each device you want it to launch on. Just discovered this by accident.

Comment: Yes but since this question was never answered, others will now know how to do this. It isn't exactly obvious in the interface.

Comment: What version of the ide are you running? If you're not running the latest you should update.

Comment: if you shold shift, select all devices, and you click "Run on the same device next time", even if it doesn't' put plural "devices" it will automatically run on all the next time.

Comment: is there a way to do this on Mac? I wasnt able to select multiple devices.

Comment: @bluebrain I could do it, just did it. Now I feel like a fool for deploying thrice to all 3 Genymotion emulators.

Comment: I am using Android Studio 1.4 now, and still not able to run my app on two devices at the same time. (on Mac ofc.)

Comment: Ohh, I just realised that I was trying to debug apps, not run. AS allows to run multi device but debug just one.

Comment: Tip: The use device as default checkbox works with multiple devices. So you don't need to select multiple every run.

Comment: I've seen this only works for a device and an emulator; not multiple emulators. Are others seeing the same?

Comment: Just so everyone is aware, Instant Run is not supported when deploying to multiple devices unfortunately.

Comment: Is there a similar option available for running tests?

Comment: There is no device selection dialog in latest canary build (3.7), we have to select devices each time we run.

Answer (score 30):

For new users, in Android Studio 2, you also need to disable "Instant Run" in Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Instant Run. See [Instant Run](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/instant-run).

With Instant Run, you only can work with one device at time.

**UPDATE**

In Android Studio 2.1, it is automatically disabled when run in multiples devices at time.

> Deploying to multiple devices
>
> Instant Run uses different techniques to perform hot, warm, and cold
>   swaps that are specific to the API level of the target device. For
>   this reason, while deploying an app to multiple devices at once,
>   Android Studio temporarily turns off Instant Run.

Comment: Android Studio 2.3, this or any of the previous answers do not work. I'm really hoping there is a solution for this.

Answer (score 9):

I got new update of Android Studio that is **Android Studio 3.5**

```
Android Studio 3.5
Build #AI-191.8026.42.35.5791312, built on August 9, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows Server 2016 10.0
```

In this update they have added [in-built option](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases?utm_source=android-studio-3-5&utm_medium=studio-assistant-stable#3-5-deploy-flow) to run application on multiple devices.

> The IDE has a new drop-down menu that lets you quickly select which
>   device you'd like to deploy your app to. This menu also includes a new
>   option that lets you run your app on multiple devices at once.

[image]

Do update new version of Android Studio and Enjoy.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't remember your selection, so you need to reselect them each time you run.

Comment: Yeah, this update is the reason I am here. It makes it worse, because the workaround and remember does not work anymore. Lets check the 3.6 Canary Release Notes :-)

Comment: Yep, was not the first one, for a follow up see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57613864/new-issue-after-update-to-android-studio-3-5-release-adb-device-selection-scree

Comment: I don't enjoy it not remembering selection in multiple devices and trying to run on an emulator if a newly plugged in device hasn't been recognized yet. They once again fixed something that was never broken. Sigh.

Comment: @RyanR it now does remember, Arctic Fox Canary 1 has this feature, bettern than ever :)

Comment: @RyanR right now i have three devices and once i select two of them for run then every time i don't have to reselect them and another thing is that you can create shortcut for opening selection menu so that you don't have click every time on device name button to select `run on multiple button` option..

Comment: @VivekThummar Excellent!

Answer (score 5):

Just as a point of addition, if you want to run your tests on multiple devices, you can't select multiple devices in the device chooser dialog for a Test profile. Instead, you need to run the gradle command `connectedCheck`. This runs your tests on all devices connected. There's no embedded UI for it (like you get running tests on a single device), but it provides a link to a locally generated HTML file with the test summary.

You can run from command line, or within AS, look in the `Gradle projects` window under: App(or root project)->Tasks->verification.

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18592367/1544046: Describes for emulators, but works for devices as well

Answer (score 3):

This feature is now available in [Android Studio 4.2.0](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases#multiple-devices). Just "Select Multiple Devices..." as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: Device Selection]

Devices are remembered and the multi selection dialog does not need to be opened each time, deploy defaults to previous selection

Only caveat is that devices that are unplugged are not remembered on re-plug

Comment: Can't wait for this to hit the stable channel. Will make multi-device testing/development so much easier.

Answer (score 2):

In Android Studio Select Dropdown option as shown below, you can select **Run on Multiple Devices**

[image]

Now Select Checkbox, in my case I have selected two Samsung phones available and then click on Run button. This will install and launch application in both the devices.

[image]

P.S: I have tested this in Android Studio 4.0, but in every run you need to use mouse in Below Android Studio 4.1.1. From Android Studio 4.1.1, there is a option to set KeyMap.

In **Android Studio 4.1.2**, you can set KeyMap Shortcut key for Run on Multiple Devices. I have set ctl+alt+R in my case as shown in below:

[image]

Comment: How do you get it to automatically run on the devices you select after the first time?

Answer (score 0):

As of Android Studio 2.3.3 
Disable the Instant Run use Menu Run->Run App (in windows shift +click for device you want to deploy)

you can't deploy to multiple devices if you used run->debug app

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to run all connected device every time. Just Select all connected device while Android Studio shows Select Deployment Target & Select "Use same selection for future launches".

N.B. Remember all devices run sequentially one by one.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Android studio 3.5. Run on multiple devices.

[image]

Comment: It still doesn't remember my selection on multiple devices

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio 2020.3.1 has the option to run on multiple devices,
But we can find multiple runs by selecting multiple devices while selecting the device(s) to run.

> Run -> Select Multiple Devices -> Check devices want to run

[image]

Answer (score -4):

Very Simple.

CTRL + Shift on every device.

That all