# Deploy on several emulators in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to deploy on several emulator devices in android studio.
Just for testing it on different devices.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

1. Start a few emulators.
2. Create run configuration that shows chooser dialog (target device).
   [image: Run configuration]
3. Run configuration.
4. Select all running emulators when Android Studio asks.
   [image: Emulator selection]

**This will work only for non debug `Android Application` configuration, it will not work for `Android Tests` or debug configurations.**

You can also run Gradle command `connectedCheck` to run tests on all devices outside of Android Studio.

Comment: +1 for the connectedCheck command to run the tests. UI Support is not integrated, but gives link to the HTML summary file which is nice

Comment: Worth mentioning, you need to create separate AVDs for each emulator instance.

Comment: Thanks - didn't even think about selecting all the emulator in the chooser and clicking on OK. What a simple solution.