# Is there a way to configure android studio to run all AVD virtual devices when run is button pressed?

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, android-virtual-device

So I'm developing a flutter app and am using the android studio's virtual devices. I have multiple virtual devices (say pixel and nexus). Now once the virtual devices are launched, to run the app on both devices: I have to press the run button (on android studio) once to run the app on the currently selected virtual device, select the next virtual device, and press the run button again to run it on the other virtual device. Now this did not seem like an issue at the start, but after a while, it was starting to bug me as you can imagine, doing this multiple times over and over again would be an enormous waste of time. Is there a way to configure it such that once all virtual devices are launched, pressing the run button once would launch the app on all virtual devices and not only the currently selected virtual device ?

[image]

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18592296/deploy-on-several-emulators-in-android-studio) but for flutter it looks a little different, what do I configure ?

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18592296/deploy-on-several-emulators-in-android-studio

Comment: @MazinIbrahim I saw that but for flutter, it looks a little different there is no target device (post updated)