# AndroidStudio: always run on all connected devices

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

How can I configure AndroidStudio such that the app is run on all connected devices without further inquiry even when I constantly plug in new devices / remove old ones?

Please note that this requires a slightly different approach than [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21251175/1531708), since with their procedure the device selection dialog appears again if you

- connect another device

or

- restart Android Studio

Comment: ask Tor Norbye to include this feature in next release. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I found a bash script that has been working well for me for quite sometime:

```
adb devices | while read line
do
    if [ ! "$line" = "" ] && [ `echo $line | awk '{print $2}'` = "device" ]
    then
        device=`echo $line | awk '{print $1}'`
        echo "$device $@ ..."
        adb -s $device $@
    fi
done
```

All credits go the github user '**christopherperry**'. For more info check this link:

https://gist.github.com/christopherperry/3208109

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, that is a good starting point, now this script has to be inserted in the AndroidStudio run configurations, I suppose? How do I find the apk just compiled by the IDE and how to I call this script with this parameter?

Comment: I can update the answer with some more details a bit later. I am currently working from a different machine..

Comment: @user251182 are you now working on the same machine? :-) Was checking my old questions and noticed this one needs an answer to be accepted

Answer (score 1):

The answer is pretty much same as the solution. The only thing to be done is "check" the checkbox that says "Always use the same device for future launches" [As highlighted in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WupCt.png)

Be sure to select all devices before you click run, for the first time.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: Perhaps, but it does the trick for me. No need to select devices for each run. All subsequent builds automatically are installed on all selected devices.

Comment: Changing the available devices (adding or removing one) makes this window appear again - I am searching for a way around that.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to run all connected device every time. Just Select all connected device while **Android Studio** shows **Select Deployment Target** & Select "Use same selection for future launches".

N.B. Remember all devices run sequentially one by one.

[image]

Comment: correct me if I am wrong, but the device selection dialog appears again if you a) connect another device or b) restart Android Studio

Comment: for new device the answer is yes. same for restart. but for same connected device it will not ask again if it is checked "Use same selection for future launches"..

Comment: then this is the same approach already mentioned in the question