# Android Studio: How to run app in 2 emulators?

Tags: android-studio

From Android Studio, I can launch 2 emulators (different devices) but I don't manage to run my applications on both. I have to choose only one device at the first run and then when I try to re-run it always run in the same one.

Is it possible to run app in 2 emulators using Android Studio? How ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run an app on a multiple devices automatically in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17496875/run-an-app-on-a-multiple-devices-automatically-in-android-studio)