# Force show "Select deployment target" dialog

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there a way to force the "Select deployment target" dialog to show in Android Studio? Currently the only method I know is to hit stop to get the dialog again. But this produces weird workflows with a lot of overhead when developing an app that runs on >=2 devices and you need to jump between targets and do not want the other app to stop. Currently I am hitting stop and then open the app from the launcher and not android studio. But I find myself often reproducing a state which I already had before. I really hope there is a magic key-stroke I did not yet find to force show this dialog ..-)

Answer (score 2):

Ctrl + shift + f10 did the trick for me.

Alternatively you can right-click on your main activity on the project pane on the left and select `run MyActivity`

Or you can simply select more than one device in "Select deployment target" dialog using shift+click.

Comment: thanks - unfortunately Ctrl + shift + f10 does nothing here - can you name the action behind this?

Comment: I cant find the action name. It is the shortcut suggested when i right click one activity and i select `run 'MyActivity'`.  
Maybe you have to disable "instant run"

Comment: Definitely you have to disable instant run. Instant run allows you to work with just 1 deploy at a time. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17496875/run-an-app-on-a-multiple-devices-automatically-in-android-studio) for more detail. Hope this help

Comment: In mac it's: Ctrl + Shift + R when selecting the activity to be run in the project explorer.