# How to install same app concurrently on multiple devices using Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, server, installation

I wonder if there is a way to install and run an android application concurrently on multiple devices/emulator with a single server that is from development machine.

Do such thing exists?

Comment: u want to run an app on multiple devices at the same time, from a computer (server)? .... so you want to create your own api server -> instead of using, for example, firebase? yes its possible

Answer (score 4):

Actually yes. When launcing your app through Android Studio, you can shift+click on the devices you want to run your application on. Discussed in more detailed in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17496875/run-an-app-on-a-multiple-devices-automatically-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

When you see the list of devices come up after launching the app,

> just `press (shift or control) + click each device` you want it to launch on.

[image]