# debug multiple device simultaneously in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging

I made one App based on Client-Server programming. I can **run** that App on multiple devices simultaneously, now I want to **debug** that App in multiple devices simultaneously so I can check the flow of both client and server simultaneously.

Is it possible in Android studio?? If yes then How can I achieve that??

Comment: It isn't supported. check the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17496875/run-an-app-on-a-multiple-devices-automatically-in-android-studio#comment52656142_21251175) on a similar question.

Comment: thanks , don't you think that IntelliJ should have to improve this feature in android studio like swift??t

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by creating multiple launch/debug configurations and assign them the same module. Then just run debug each configuration on different device.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can start multiple instants by ctrl selecting your devices in the 'Deployment Target Options' pane.

There's annotation prepended in the 'Run' pane on which device is outputting... [DEVICE]-[DEVICE_NAME]-[SERIAL_NUM]

Comment: it is for Run ..i am talking about Debug multiple device...please read my question carefully