# New issue after update to Android Studio 3.5 release. ADB device selection screen will not come up when running app (SHIFT-F10)

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, adb

New Issue: When Running app on Android Studio 3.5 the device selection screen no longer appears. It defaults to "random" device.

Tried looking for answers on Google. No go. Tried looking in Settings. No go. Searched menus in Android Studio.  No go.

Expected the device selection screen (Physical and emulated devices) to come up. It does not. Just defaults to seemingly random device.  All emulators work and are present as are my physical devices.

My question is: How do I select which device I wish to deploy to. A drop down menu has been mentioned, but I am unable to locate it.

Comment: Okay it has been found. Toolbar top right. My screen is quite large and the toolbar is small. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! As outlined in the "[What's new](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases#3-5-0)" section of Android Studio, the *Device selector* is now a "combo box/dropdown" menu.

> The IDE has a new drop-down menu that lets you quickly select which device you'd like to deploy your app to. This menu also includes a new option that lets you run your app on multiple devices at once.

Whether this option can be disabled or not, is something I couldn't find so far.

It's better than the old dialog, but it makes "dynamic" device selection harder unless you go with your mouse... click on it.. you get the picture. In that regard, I believe the new control is *worse* than the previous 3.4.x Android Studio with the all-known dialog chooser.

On the pro side, you can select multiple ones, and shift-F10 (default run on Windows/Linux), will send the apk to all selected devices.

So for the most use case (re-running on 1 or more devices) this is a good improvement. Even if the emulator is not running.

But for the other cases where you are changing which device you use, this is a usability regression, (as far as I know) because you can't *easily* focus that, change it with the keyboard, and run. So... there's that.

We'll see if Google does something about this or provides a way to "navigate" this with the keyboard in a fancy way like it was possible before.

For what is worth, [here's the Issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139859272) in the Google Tracker.

Comment: Is there any way to have a one click (or keystroke) solution to run on multiple devices by default. It was possible in the old AS (its not the most common case, but nice if you refactor UI stuff)

Comment: Okay it has been found. Toolbar top right. My screen is quite large and the toolbar is small. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @ChristianRuppert Not as far as I have found yet.